# How do I render a viewport animation that includes the visible name of each object?

Tags: rendering, animation, 3d-view

I have a scene with a lot of object names visible in the viewport. However, when I render a preview viewport animation, the names are no longer visible. I went through as many settings and preferences as I could, hunting around for an option that would allow me to render with object names visible, but I couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to do this, and if so, how?

Comment: Strange, the wireframe option also shows up in viewport render and that's under the same viewport display sub bar... so there must be something specific with the names.

Comment: maybe a bug...?

Comment: @RichSedman Yes, it does answer my question, although it's a bit more complicated than I had hoped it would be, given the nature of my scene. I might just do a screen record instead of rendering, since this is a project for practical purposes rather than artistic purposes.